# Petición: Diferenciar claramente el estilo de los encabezados por nivel

Tags: característica-nueva, diseño

La diferencia de estilo en los encabezados es demasiado sutil. Favor de diferenciarlos claramente. Ejemplo

**"En vivo"**

## Nivel 1

### Nivel 2

#### Nivel 3

**Imagen**

> [image: Estilos de niveles de encabezados]

**Imagen de la app móvil**

> [image: Captura aplicación móvil]

Comment: Me parece que esto aplica a nivel de todos los sitios de SE, no se si sea posible, acabo de probar en [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/) y es igual de sutil

Comment: @CésarBustíos : No debería ser tan complicado porque en la app móvil la diferencia es más notoria.